# Tracking group upload with widget

Tags: uploadcare

I deployed [Uploadcare](https://uploadcare.com) and would like to track the widget multifilepick progress. My code:

```
function placeOrder(){
      var widgets = uploadcare.initialize();
      var widget = uploadcare.MultipleWidget('[role=uploadcare-uploader][data-multiple]');
      widget.onUploadComplete(function(info) {
            $('#orderForm').find('[type="submit"]').trigger('click');
        });   
  };
```

Trying to execute a submit button only when the upload is complete. Here are the issues:

1. If a user clicks the button during upload the trigger gets fired immediately the upload completes taking away control from the user.
2. If a user clicks the button only after upload completes, nothing happens.

Anyone out there that can help? Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve here. Do you want to submit form when upload is complete? Do you want to disable submit while uploading is in progress?

Comment: will [this](http://jsbin.com/lekuc/4/watch) help?

Comment: @mojo Thanks for this... didn't do the trick, but pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: could you update you question to make things bit clearer, so I could give a proper answer for everyone in the future to find :)